# Android Q displays wrong gradient orientation

Tags: android, background, gradient, android-relativelayout

Since i updated my device to android 10 im facing a weird problem with one of my background gradients.

I have a RelativeLayout with a gradient background drawable looking like this.

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:id="@+id/layoutSpeedLegend"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="18dp"
  android:background="@drawable/background"/>
```

My background.xml is looking like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">

        <gradient
            android:centerColor="@color/yellow"
            android:endColor="@color/red"
            android:startColor="@color/darkgreen"
            android:centerX="50%"/>

        <corners android:radius="15dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

In the editors preview, everything looks fine [image]

But on my real test device is looks like this. [image]

Also adding `android:angle="90"` to my background.xml doesn't work.

Does anybody have an idea why this happens?

Comment: Have you tried `android:angle="0"`? 0 is left to right, 90 is bottom to top

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint. I thought that angle="0" is the default. But it looks like since android 10 you have to apply this property. Now it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bug reported [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141903681). And may not be resolved yet.

The workaround is set angle="0" as you mentioned in question's comment.

Comment: Any workaround for the workaround because it still needs to work properly on non-Q devices?

Comment: Create a specific background.xml in a drawables-v29 folder which contains the angle="0" and leave the general one in drawables folder

Comment: This worked but It's so strange. Why need to set angle when it's already fine?